# OTP Input in Kotlin - library android-otpview-pinview

Tags: android, kotlin, one-time-password

I am using below library in my Android application to provide UI for OTP :

https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview

Successfully, Added dependency as below :

```
implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:2.1.0'
```

Also, added below line :

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Using it in layout as below :

```
       <com.mukesh.OtpView
        android:id="@+id/otp_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:itemBackground="@drawable/drawable_otp_entry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemCount="4"
        app:lineColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:viewType="none" />
```

Now, at the kotlin side in my activity am doing like this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var otpView: OtpView? =null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    otpView = findViewById(R.id.otp_view)
    otpView.setListener(object:OnOtpCompletionListener() {
        override fun onOtpCompleted(otp:String) {
            // do Stuff
            Log.d("onOtpCompleted=>", otp)
        }
    })
    }
}
```

Error is at line :  **`otpView.setListener(object:OnOtpCompletionListener() {`** saying **Unresolved reference : setListener** and **The class does not have a Constructor**

am using kotlin and library is might in Java.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Try removing () from OnOtpCompletionListener()

Comment: okay it's fine.  What about Unresolved reference : setListener ?

Comment: if you have removed that then what's the issue now?

Comment: Error : The class does not have a cnostructor GONE, but Error: Unresolved is there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetListener is not supported anymore i guess, try using

```
 otpView = findViewById(R.id.otp_view)
    otpView!!.setOtpCompletionListener(object :OnOtpCompletionListener
    {
        override fun onOtpCompleted(otp: String?) {

        }

    })
```

Comment: I have done like this : 

otpView?.setOtpCompletionListener(object:OnOtpCompletionListener {
            override fun onOtpCompleted(otp:String) {
                

and it's also working. Which is better ?

Comment: !! through an exception if value is null, ? will return null.